# Set textarea value with javascript after TinyMCE initializing

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, textarea

I hava an textarea and I am using tinyMCE on that textarea.

What I am doing actually is that when the page is opened, I am populating the textarea with some text, and after that I am initializing the tinyMCE.

The problem is when I am trying to change the value of the textarea after tinyMCE initializing, then nothing happens.

Here is an example.

1. Creating the textarea:

   ```
   <textarea style="width: 95%;" name="title"  id="title"></textarea>
   ```
2. Populating the textarea:

   ```
   $('#title').html("someText");
   ```
3. Initializing tinyMCE

   ```
   tinyMCE.init({
           // General options
           mode : "specific_textareas",
           theme : "advanced",
           width: "100%",
           plugins : "pagebreak,paste,fullscreen,visualchars",

           // Theme options
           theme_advanced_buttons1 : "code,|,bold,italic,underline,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,|,fullscreen,|,bullist,numlist,|,pasteword",
           theme_advanced_buttons2 :"",
           theme_advanced_buttons3 :"",
           theme_advanced_buttons4 :"",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
           theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
           valid_elements : "i,sub,sup",
           invalid_elements : "p, script",
           editor_deselector : "mceOthers"
       });
   ```
4. I would like to change the content of the textview (but it is not working)

I have tryed to use the same as before init the tinyMCE

```
    $('#title').html("someModifiedText"); // does not work
```

I have also tryed to remove tinyMCE:

```
    if(tinyMCE.getInstanceById('title'))
    removeTinyMCE("title");
```

With

```
function removeTinyMCE (dialogName) {
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, dialogName);
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, dialogName);
```

}

And thet to reuse:

```
    $('#title').html("someModifiedText"); // does not work
```

I am out of ideas... Thank you very much for your help....

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Problem here is you won't see anything if you enter text or html into your textarea.
Your textarea gets hidden when tinymce gets initialized. What you see then is a content editable iframe, which is used to edit and style content. There are several events which will cause tinymce to write its content to the html source element of the editor (in your case your textarea).

If you want to set the content of the editor (which is visible) you will need to call something like

```
tinymce.get('title').setContent('<p>This is my new content!</p>');
```

You may also acces the dom elements directly using the following

```
tinymce.get('title').getBody().innerHTML = '<p>This is my new content!</p>';
```

or using jQuery

```
$(tinymce.get('title').getBody()).html('<p>This is my new content!</p>');
```

Comment: Thanks again Thariama, I am geting an error here: tinymce.get('title') is undefined

Comment: refer to [this](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent).

Comment: @goldenparrot, thank you, I allready tryed that but still the same problem.

Comment: you need to use your textareas id, but you may also use tinymce.activeEditor or tinymce.editors[0]

Comment: @Thariama, my textarea id is "title" as shown in the question. I have 5 textareas on the same page, shuld I use tinymce.editors[0] for the first one, tinymce.editors[1] for the second etc ?

Comment: The textarea id matches the editorid, so when you tell me your textarea has the id titel then there should be an editor with the id "title". It is more elegant to use tinymce.activeEditor, but this will result in an error if no editor has been in use (example freshly loaded page; you will have no problem if you execute your code after an editor has been activated). tinymce.editors[0...4] will only work if they get initialized in the same order every time.

Comment: Thank you again @Thariama. To give you more details, I have 5 textareas with different ids. The first one is with the id "title". I am tryint to use tinymce.get('title').setcontent('<p>This is my new content!</p>'); but I am getting the error that tinymce.get('title') is undefined !!!

Comment: can you shown me the result in your console of "tinymce.editors[0].id" ?

Comment: setcontent doesn't work for me, but setContent does (with a capital "C")

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span>');`

This Works For Latest Version 6.8.2

[Check this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780766/setcontent-of-an-textarea-with-tinymce/34034158#34034158)

Comment: If you feel that this question is a duplicate, it should be flagged as such.  Please don't post links to other Stack Overflow questions as an answer.

Comment: sorry didn't notice the same user's post. thanks for the info.

Comment: great solution !!

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. Simple great solution! Thanks @RyanMonreal

Answer (score 2):

Simply this works for me

```
$("#description").val(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem solved by making sure the `setContent` was done after the document is ready, so first;

```
script(type="text/javascript").
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#title',
    height: 350,
    menubar: false
  });
```

then

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  $(document).ready(function(){
    tinymce.get('title').setContent('<span>someText</span> is html');
  })
```

Above is code for pug, but the key is -as mentioned- to load it on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="content" name="content">{{html_entity_decode($yourstringdata)}}</textarea>
```

This is work for me, Decode your html data and place it between start and closing textarea tags.

Answer (score 0):

once call this

```
tinymce.triggerSave();
```

then value of tinymce will be transferred to the original textarea value. So so can get that as you get from normal textarea.

Answer (score -6):

It works for me. Just place it inside your html code instead of going tinymce

```
    <textarea> html CONTENT</textarea>
```

Comment: The question is about using tinyMCE in a specific way, but the solution presented here just says, don't use tinymce, which doesn't help answer the question at all.